# iOS 17 and Flutter Custom URL Scheme

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking, applinks, custom-scheme-url

When I implement **Custom URL Scheme** to my app all works fine, but after **iOS 17** update. Devices with this iOS version can't handle my Custom URL Scheme.
On **previous version of Xcode** I successfully run this method to test my links:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted mycustomscheme://some:action:here
```

But after Xcode update the same command have "Invalid URL" as a result.

Also this line work fine:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted mycustomscheme://some/action/here
```

And links with same format work fine `mycustomscheme://some/action/here`

Is there some changes with Custom URL Scheme validation on the last update or something like this? Does it described somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried uri-encoding your colons?  As in `some%72action%72here` ?

Comment: Hmm, I use batch to send notification with that deeplinks, and first of all I try to understand what changes in last iOS version. And where I can read more about this changes. But thanks.